# Как сделать 3-й символ строки в верхнем регистре?

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Как привести 3-й символ строки в верхний регистр?

```
$str = 'abcdef';
```

Comment: Just do it!!!!!

Answer (score 3):

Для не utf-8 строк (как в вопросе) к элементам строки можно обращаться следующим образом

```
$str{2} = strtoupper($str{2});
echo  $str; // abCdef
```

А для utf-8 придется воспользоваться mb_substr() (или просто substr() при правильных настройках php)

Comment: Спасибо. А как, например, проверить: если 3-й символ в нижнем регистре, тогда нужно привести его в верхний. С помощью регулярных выражений?..

Comment: Если все равно приводить, то и не нагружайте прогу проверками, а так да или сравнением с `a` и `z` , или регуляркой

Comment: А как правильно проверить?)

Comment: `$c = $str{2}; if($c >='a' and $c<='z') {}`

Comment: @splash58, а как насчёт не-латинских алфавитов и прочих разных не-английских языков?

Comment: @alexanderbarakin начнем с того, что для utf-8 мой ответ неверен

Comment: @splash58, так, может, стоит дополнить и для не-латиницы? ну, или хотя бы оговорку добавить.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin про оговорку я готов согласится, но не хочу додумывать вопрос за автора :)

Comment: @splash58, но ведь ответы здесь пишутся не только и не столько для автора вопроса, сколько для тех, кто придёт из поиска. это и есть суть базы знаний. и развёрнутый ответ на казалось бы элементарный вопрос (который на самом деле не так уж прост) — это для базы знаний истинное сокровище.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin наверное, вы правы, но что поделать, люди разные. Я обычно решаю более утилитарную задачу. вот живой пример, представляете если этот текст копировать в ответы на каждый вопрос про массив - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30680938/how-can-i-access-an-array-object/30681327#30681327